# Is that a normal email address: 131fo29916434ef@email.domain.com

Tags: email, domain

In a c# application that has a class for sending emails, i found that the email message is BCC to an email with the following format: `131fo29916434ef@email.domain.co`

Is this a normal email address that I can access its inbox? If so, how can I open it?

Comment: Often when emails are addressed like that it is because the recipient is another application - the receiving application will act on the content of the email.  Trello does this for example, and lets you add a card via email.  Can you tell us more about the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perfectly valid email address in terms of syntax, according to the [RFC 2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822) (you will find a more accessible explanation on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address).

However, although it is syntaxically valid, this email does not seem to point to a valid mailbox. I suppose that this email address is a default setting included in the source of your class, or even in your application.

Could you please tell us more about where you got this application? Do you have access to the source code?

Comment: Thanks to your reply and @Paul's comment. It turned out to be used by an application at the domain to save a copy of  email message. I appreciate your help